# How can I search and replace backticks with <code> </code> tags?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I have a large text file with multiple instances of text that are enclosed by 3 backticks:

````
    ```
Default:
Publisher Bid Modifier Object with values=[]
    ```

   <td>

    ```
Publisher Bid Modifier Object
    ```

   </td>
````

I want replace those backticks with `<code> </code>` tags, to look like this:

```
    <code>
Default:
Publisher Bid Modifier Object with values=[]
    </code>

   <td>

    <code>
Publisher Bid Modifier Object
    </code>


   </td>
```

How could I search and replace using a text editor like VS Code (or similar)? I am using a MacBook.

Many thanks!

Comment: You could write a program using Python. Would you like me to show you how?

Comment: I have never used Python before. If you think it will be fairly straightforward for me to  get up and running, then by all means. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, Python is a great language for beginners because it allows users to interact with their code unlike other languages. You can download the latest version of Python here: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-374/

Comment: Thanks AlexS and virolino

I might not be able to provide feedback on my side for the next day or 2. But many thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regex:

````
```([^`]*)```
````

and replace it with

```
<code>\1</code>
```

- `<code>` and `</code>` are just text strings, can be anything;
- `\1` is the first [**capture group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) from the search string; additionally you can have `\2`, `\3` ..., depending on what you search;

---

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/VqojbA/1).

---

However, make yourself a service and verify that the "tags" are properly matched, either before, or after the replacement. It will be quite tricky to catch an even number of mismatches.

Comment: Thanks, virolino

That seems to work very nicely. And the website provided for test driving it is very useful too.

Question: can you explain the 'substitution value' piece? What sort of values can I plug in there?

Comment: I added to the answer.

Comment: Prefect! Thanks :)

Comment: Done :) (Sorry - I'm a bit rusty on how to use StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

We will be using regular expressions to find and replace data within your text file.

Regular expressions search for patterns within some form of data. The data could be an HTML file, a word file (assuming you know how to extract the text), or in your case an ordinary text file. To implement a regular expression, you need to use use special characters to denote certain features of the pattern. The findall function takes the following form:

```
re.findall(pattern,string)
```

For example, if you wanted to find all the words "staircase" within a document, you would write

```
re.findall("staircase",text)
```

where "staircase" is the pattern, and text is the string. The program would return all instances of "staircase" as an array in the text you used as an input. But what if you wanted to also include capitalized versions of staircase, i.e. "Staircase", supposing it were at the beginning of a sentence for example? In this case, you have use the special characters I was referring to earlier: you would write the following pattern instead

```
re.findall("(S|s)taircase",text)
```

The | metacharacter means either the content on the left, or the content on the right. Also notice how parentheses are used to group items together, which is common in regular expressions. So the regex searches for either of the following strings: "Staircase", or "staircase". Some other important metacharacters in regular expressions are

"\w" matches any "word" character, so "a", "b", "C", and "D" would all be matched with this metacharacter.

"\W" matches any non-word character, so "1", "2", ">", "?", and "=" would all be matched by this metacharacter.

"\s" matches any whitespace character.

"\S" matches any non-whitespace character.

"\d" matches all the digit characters, 0-9.

"\D" matches any non-digit character.

In addition to the previous metacharacters are the quantifiers *, +, ?, {n}, {min,}, and {min, max}. Here's a brief description of these meta characters:

"*" matches zero or more occurrences of the previous element.

"+" matches one or more occurrences of the previous element.

"?" matches zero or one occurrences of the previous element.

"{n}" matches exactly n occurrences of the previous element.

"{min,}" matches at least min occurrences of the previous element.

"{min,max}" matches between min and max occurrences of the previous element (including min and max).

So to give an example of what we've covered so far, here is an example of a pattern using grouping, the or symbol, a quantifier, and a metacharacter.

```
re.findall("(A|a)pple\d*",text)
```

The regex would find all of the following substrings: "Apple", "apple", "Apple0", "apple0", "Apple00", "apple00", etc.

Now that we've gotten through the introduction to regular expressions, we can move on to actually writing the code to solve your problem using Python.

````
import re
textFile = open(pathToTextFile,"r")
rawText = textFile.read()
textFile.close()
tags = ["<code>","</code>"]
count = 0
output = ""
for line in rawText.split("\n"):
    if "```" in line:
        output+=re.sub("```",tags[count%2],line)+"\n"
        count+=1
    else:
        output+=line+"/n"
outFile = open(pathToOutFile,"w")
outFile.write(output)
outFile.close()
````

If you have Python installed on your computer, open up IDLE and create a new file. A new window will open. This is where you write your commands.

The first thing we need to do is import a package called re, which is a module used for regular expressions. Then we load the text file (insert your path), read its contents, and close the text file.

Next we define an array called tags that holds the two tags that we will be using to replace the three quotes, an integer called count that determines what tag will be added, and an empty output string.

Then  we iterate on each new line of the rawText variable and whenever we see the triple quotes, we replace with one of the tags, and then update the count variable. Otherwise, we simply add the line and move on to the next element of the for loop.

Lastly, we create a new file for writing (insert your path), write the output string, and close the file. And we're done! The output is shown below.

```
    <code>
Default:
Publisher Bid Modifier Object with values=[]
    </code>

   <td>

    <code>
Publisher Bid Modifier Object
    </code>

   </td>
```

Refs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression;

Comment: Hi, Alex

Many thanks for your input. When I have a bit of time later this week, I would be more than keen to test drive it.

I marked virolino's answer as correct, because it's closer to what I asked - i.e. a search and replace (without writing code).

But your input is much appreciated (and your approach is also a viable alternative).

Thanks again
Pete